# Using IF(Isnumber(Search) formula - Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking for a formula that:

If c7 contains text: "Payables" OR "Corporate" then Text 1, if false then "Text 2"

Currently using formula =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Payables",$c7)),"Text 1","Text 2") - as I had not identified "Corporate" as a criteria - but need it to be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is "Payables" or "Corporate" a cell value or is it a sentence? What I mean is, is there any spaces or just one single value in this cell? It makes a HUGE difference on the solution. In regards to your "contains text" comment. If it's only one word or a single value with no spaces, number or string, then it's not "contains", but rather "equal to".

Comment: Thanks ejbytes, - the cell contains a sentence that could contain letters or numbers. - so Corporate or Payables can appear anywhere in that cell

Comment: Okay then, I think that should work for you now in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C7 contains a single value, with no spaces, number or text then this will suffice:

```
=IF(OR($C$7="Corporate",$C$7="Payables"), "Text True", "Text False")
```

If C7 is a sentence, then you want to check for errors in findings:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("Corporate",$C$7),0),IFERROR(SEARCH("Payables",$C$7),0)),"True Text", "False Text")
```